# Ruby Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError deprecation warning

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I am trying to run a script on a new server and I get the following error:

```
WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
```

So far I am not able to figure out the cause of this issue.

Modules:

> headless (2.3.1) selenium-webdriver (3.142.7) watir (6.16.5)
>   ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.87

Any ideas / suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the W3C browser capability, it should be true.

Comment: Thank you reply. I tried this in different variations with no success so far.

Comment: try updating chromedriver?  current v is ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106.  you want it to match your chrome, see here for more: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection  can you share the portion of the script that fails?